# ¿Por qué el switch termina de forma inesperada?

Tags: java, switch, modular

lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un switch de reserva de hospedaje en java, pero no me deja terminar de reportar los datos ingresados, porque termina el programa de manera inesperada, y no me deja pasar a la opción de consultar datos ingresados, al momento de hacer el reporte final de los datos ingresados ya no permite continuar

```
 package Main;
    import BaseDatosHospedaje.accesoDatos;
    import Datos.Huesped;
    import Datos.Habitacion;
    import Datos.Empleado;
    import Datos.FichaHospedaje;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Presentación {
        static BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


     
        //Variables
        static int n=0;
        static long nro;
        static FichaHospedaje oF;
        static Habitacion oH;
        static Huesped oHspd;
        static accesoDatos huespedes=new accesoDatos();
        static accesoDatos fichas=new accesoDatos();
        static accesoDatos habitaciones=new accesoDatos();
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int opc;
            do{
                opc=menu();
                switch(opc){
                    case 1: n=leerN();
                           ingresar();
                           break;
                    case 2: listar();
                           break;              
                }
            }while(opc!=3);
        }
        static int menu() throws IOException{
        int opc;
        do{
           System.out.println("---MENÚ DE OPCIONES---");
           System.out.println("1. Registrar Huesped");
           System.out.println("2. Consultar Huesped");
           System.out.println("3. SALIR");
           System.out.println("Ingrese la opción: ");
           opc=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }while(opc<1 || opc>2);
        return opc;
        }
        static int leerN()throws IOException{
            int n;
            do{  
                System.out.println("Ingrese número de huéspedes a registrar: ");
                n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }while(n<=0||n>=50);
            return n;
        }


        static void ingresar()throws IOException{
            double precio, total;
            int nroDias, dni, numero;
            char tipo, estado;
            String correo, nombres, direccion;
    
            System.out.println("---Datos de Reserva---");
            System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del cliente: ");
            System.out.println("Nombres: ");
            nombres = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Dni: ");
            dni=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Direccion: ");
            direccion=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Correo: ");
            correo=br.readLine();
            oHspd=new Huesped(nombres, direccion, dni, correo);
            nombres=huespedes.regitrarHuespedes(oHspd);
            System.out.println("Dias a quedarse: ");
            nroDias=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Ingrese tipo de Habitacion: ");
            tipo=(char)System.in.read();
            


            if(tipo=='S'){
             numero=1;
             precio=300;
             estado='O';
             total=nroDias*precio;
                System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                System.out.println(oF.toString());
                
            }
            if(tipo=='D'){
             numero=1;
             precio=400;
             estado='O';
             total=nroDias*precio;
                System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                  oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                System.out.println(oF.toString());
            }
            if(tipo=='M'){
             numero=1;
             precio=500;
             estado='O';
             total=nroDias*precio;
                System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                  oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                System.out.println(oF.toString());
            }
        }
        static void listar()throws IOException{
            System.out.println("--Reporte--");
            System.out.println(huespedes.listarHuespedes());
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hEIOqd-AjZIslfmAsJlabegpYzmaH_0B?usp=sharing CODIGO

Comment: Añade el código a tu pregunta, nadie abrirá ese link, amigo.

Comment: En vez de poner spam se pone el mensaje de error como texto para que todos tengan acceso a los detalles de tu pregunta. En vez de poner spam se pone el mensaje de error como texto para que todos tengan acceso a los detalles de tu pregunta. En vez de poner spam se pone el mensaje de error como texto para que todos tengan acceso a los detalles de tu pregunta. En vez de poner spam se pone el mensaje de error como texto para que todos tengan acceso a los detalles de tu pregunta. Las validaciones están ahí para ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el codigo en el texto de la pregunta. Debes poner en que clase y en que linea da el error y cual es el error para que se te pueda ayudar de una mejor manera.

En la clase Presentacion, Linea 75, debes leer el dato usando el objeto de BufferReader y luego extraer el caracter.

Esto:
`tipo=(char)System.in.read();`

Debes cambiarlo por esto:
`tipo= br.readLine().charAt(0);`